# How to repeat different pic?

Tags: mysql

I wan to always display the different pic. So there's a problem with looping the different pic. How do i do that?

index.php:

```
<?php

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table2", $connection );
echo '<ul>'; 

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    if ($row)
        echo "<li>";

    echo "<img src='code.php?id=3'>";
    echo "&nbsp"; 
    echo "</p>";
    echo "</li>";
    echo "<br/>" ; 
}

echo '</ul>';
mysql_close($connection);

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pull the id value from the database. If you have a column called, maybe `id` you would want to put:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    if ($row){ 
        echo "<li>";
        echo "<img src='code.php?id=".$row['id']."'/>"; // see what I did there?
        echo "&nbsp"; 
        echo "</p>"; // take this out
        echo "</li>";
        echo "<br/>"; // take this out 
    } 
}
```

P.S. - don't write new code using the deprecated mysql extension. Use PDO or mysqli at least. And don't put `<br />`s between your `<li>`s, or close unopened `<p>`s. And, generally speaking, don't store your images in your database - just store the path to the image and put the images themselves in a folder on the server where they belong.

And please format your code - it is hard to read with no indentation or separation of files (your if statement was not properly enclosing what should have been conditioned statements). And `mysql_real_escape_string` is not as cool as you think it is.

Hope this helps.